# Examples of explicit computations of log-resolutions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, resolution-of-singularities

I have been working with log-resolutions lately and learning more about them. I am aware that in general producing explicit log-resolutions is difficult, but I was wondering if this has been done in some cases apart from trivial ones and Teitler's computation in  https://www.jstor.org/stable/20535332?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents, which I have already gone through.

PS. I have studied the basics of Hironaka's work (on Kollar's lecture notes), but I have not gone through the very details, because that would have brought me too off-topic for the moment. Does Hironaka's construction give (or at least suggest) a way to get log-resolutions in explicit cases?

Comment: Resolution of singularities has been implemented in Maple and Singular as I understand it.  See for instance:  https://www3.risc.jku.at/projects/adjoints/blowup/  However, that implementation was from a long time ago (when I was in graduate school).